# Angular Behavior: Property Type Changes from SignalFunction to Boolean

Tags: angular, typescript, signals

I’m encountering an interesting behavior in my Angular application, and I’m hoping someone can shed some light on it. Here’s the scenario:
I have a working code snippet where I define a property called `isSelection` like this:

```
public isSelection = model.required<boolean>();
public getTypeof(value: any): string {
    return typeof value;
}
```

The isSelection property is initialized with a model.required signal

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isSelection" />
<p>{{ getTypeof(isSelection) }}</p>
```

I bind the isSelection property to a checkbox input using `[(ngModel)]`

The paragraph displays the type of `isSelection`.
In this case the isSelection is displayed as a function when i press the checkbox the type of the isSelection never changed.

However, when I change the property declaration to:

```
public isSelection = input.required<boolean>();
```

The behavior changes, and the type of isSelection seems to switch from a function to a `boolean`.

NB I'm using the last version of angular 17.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.required<boolean>()` -> meant for one way binding, but you are using for two way binding, so the function gets replaced by a value that is `boolean`

To remedy this, we can use one way binding in HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="isSelection2" />
```

When I use the code provided as a child and provide inputs from the parent, angular just throws an error when I try to use `[(ngModel)]="isSelection2"`

`model.required<boolean>()` -> meant for two way binding, so your example works perfectly, since it does exactly what it's supposed to do!

See the below code/Stackblitz:

child

```
import { Component, input, model } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isSelection" />
    <pre>{{ isSelection() }}</pre>
    <p>{{ getTypeof(isSelection) }}</p>
    <hr />
    <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="isSelection2" />
    <pre>{{ isSelection2() }}</pre>
    <p>{{ getTypeof(isSelection2) }}</p>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  public isSelection = model.required<boolean>();
  public isSelection2 = input.required<boolean>();

  public getTypeof(value: any): string {
    return typeof value;
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './app/child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `<app-child [isSelection2]="true" [isSelection]="false"/>`,
})
export class App {}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nzaqkj?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Why is this possible isn't it supposed to generate some kind of error or an exception in the console ?
How  can a function change the entire type of and element from a function to a boolean

Comment: @HichamBouchikhi I updated my answer when an error gets generated from angular, when I use it on a child component!

Comment: I didn't understand the response sorry. 
My question was why I don't have any kind of error when the input.required is in double binding I'm talking about the console why it force the value instead of doing nothing or putting an error in the console

Comment: @HichamBouchikhi In the below stackblitz please try toggling the second checkbox and check the console, we are getting an error as expected, due to new signal api, we need to implement it in a particular way, only then we are getting the error, do share back the stackblitz with the issues when no console error comes, I will look into it, but as of now, I am able to get an error when I toggle the second checkbox [check this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wpgg6l)

Comment: Ah thank you i get it, in my case I didn't get the error that's why I was puzzled